# Script Intel Graphics Driver's brightness

Tags: display, automation, vga, brightness

On my old PC I have

- a dumb VGA desktop monitor (without DDC control)
- integrated Intel graphics graphics card (just signal level, not illumination)

the only way to change brightness is on front panel and over driver's settings.

[brightness control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pPlL.png)

So instead of doing manually every night, would it be possible to **script that slider externally** on Windows?